# More information from std::exception

Tags: c++, qt, exception, gcc

I'm writting an QT-application for ARM-processor. I use gcc-linaro-arm-linux-gnueabihf compiller.

I try to caught std::exception

```
try
{        
   ----CODE HERE----
}
catch(QException e)
{
    qCritical() << e.what();
}
catch(std::exception e)
{
    qCritical() << e.what();
}
```

As output I have:

```
----- Dev started -----
std::exception
----- Dev finished -----
```

There is no detailed information about an exception.

Ho can I see what kind of std::excpetpion occured?

The another problem, that it's qt application. Makefile is generated by qmake. I can't directly pass options to gcc compiller.

Comment: If it is not your exception, you can't get detailed description. If it is your exception, your can put detailed information when you create exception object.

Comment: Man, instead of `e.what()` you need logger https://translate.google.com/translate?sl=auto&tl=en&u=https://habr.com/ru/post/313686/ . Why you need Logging: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Instrumentation_(computer_programming) , https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tracing_(software) , https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Log4j#Ports

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The problem is that you're *slicing* the exception object—you're catching it by value, so any subclass information is lost. Catch it by `const &` instead to keep its type & data alive:

```
catch(const std::exception &e)
{
    qCritical() << e.what();
}
```

Additionally, if you want special handling for more specific types (classes derived from `std::exception`), you can add it:

```
catch (const std::invalid_argument &e)
{
  qCritical() << "Invalid argument: " << e.what();
}
catch (const std::domain_error &e)
{
  qCritical() << "Domain error: " << e.what();
}
catch (const std::excetion &e)
{
  qCritical() << "Other exception: " << e.what();
}
```

Note that the order of `catch` clauses is important: they are processed sequentially, and the first one matching is used. So derived classes have to be listed before the base class.

Answer (score 2):

I'm not sure I have correctly understood your problem, but straightly answering your question is easy:

```
try
{        
   ----CODE HERE----
}
catch(const QException& e)
{
    qCritical() << "QException exception\n" << e.what();
}
catch(const std::exception& e)
{
    qCritical() << "standard library exception\n" << e.what();
}
```

Don't forget that if another type of exception is thrown, you can always catch it with this:

```
catch(...)
{
    qCritical() << "bad bad things happened, unknown exception!\n";
}
```